# iOS panGesture with images from NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios

I everyone,

I have a NSArray with images and wan't to be able to pass from one image to the other by panning left or right (just like in the iPhone photo library). My array of pictures come from a collection view. So the first displayed image is the one I selected in the collection view.

For now, I can display the right image and move this image left or right but I don't know how to display the other images and when an image is more than 50% in my view it moves to center.

Thank's a lot.

Here's my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //NSLog(@"%i", _indexPhoto);

    self.photoImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[_photosCollectionArray objectAtIndex:_indexPhoto]];


    UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget: self action: @selector(panGestureHandle:)];

    [recognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [recognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];

}


-(void) panGestureHandle:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *) sender {

    NSLog(@"Pan Gesture Handling");
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pangesture = (UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender;
    CGPoint translation = [pangesture translationInView:self.view];

    CGPoint imageViewPosition = _photoImageView.center;
    imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;

    _photoImageView.center = imageViewPosition;
    [pangesture setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

Comment: Use a `UIScrollView` and populate it with 3 images at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` is not the right one to use, since it is a discrete gesture and the message associated to it is sent just once.

What you need is a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`: this will allow you to track the finger movement and animate the image accordingly.

This is a basic example of how the gesture handling could be done:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

  CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
  recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, 
                                     recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
  [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

}
```

EDIT:

To be able to show the other image next to the one you are panning around, you basically need to do the following:

1. add all 3 images (say, prevImage, curImage, nextImage) to your view so that they are displayed one next to the other;
2. when you pan around curImage, you also move the other ones;
3. when curImage displacement exceeds 50% of the current view, you animate it completely off screen (and also animate next/prevImage so that it is fully displayed).

You could handle the 3 images by using `UIImageView` or `CALayer`.

This is a very basic scheme which is just fine if you prefer working from within a `UIViewController`. You might also think of having a custom `UIView` holding the three images (inside of `CALayers`) and juggling them around in `layoutSubviews`.

In any case, since I suppose you have more that 3 images, you will also need some logics so that the set of 3 images you are dealing with is updated when you move to the next image. This would add a 4th point to the above listed ones:

1. after moving to the next (previous) image:

   4.1 set prevImage (nextImage) so that it points to curImage;

   4.2 set curImage to point to nextImage (prevImage);

   4.3 make nextImage (previImage) point to the next (previous) image in the array.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you sergio, I can now move my image left and right but I can't have my other images next to the selected image. How can I display them and center them when more than 50% of the image is into the view  like in the iPhone photo library? Thanks man.

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear with what I want. Thanks

Comment: Ok so... I made some progress. I have a custom view (960 * 504) for 3 CALayer. Each layer contain one image. But now I'm blocked again. I can't use panGesture on my CALayers. What is the way to do this? And I've another problem, my images are stretched to the full size of my controller. Can I set it to "aspect fit" somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: the gesture recognizer should be associated to the view containing the layers; within the gesture recognizer method, you would "juggle" with the layers (e.g., you set the current one's opacity to 0, and the next one opacity to 1). As to the stretch, you should set the CALayer frame to the image size. You could also check CALayer `contentsGravity`.

Comment: :-) yeah that's great! So now I've to animate after 50% and replace prevImage with currImage etc. But also when I rotate the iPhone, the picture goes at the bottom of the screen, near to be fully outside. How can I detect the orientation to set different size for my UIView? Thanks your help is great!

Comment: I suggest searching SO for autorotation... set properly the autoresizingMask of your view and it should just work...

Comment: Hey, I found this : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html isn't it a great solution?

Answer (score 0):

What I would personally do is create a new `UIImageView` off the screen and then animate it coming into the screen while the other one is animated going out of the screen.

This off course if you don't care about having the animation follow the finger movement, if you do you should use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` as @sergio suggested in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest trick is to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` or put the views directly into a `UIScrollView`.

Then check when the user has stopped dragging (e.g. delegate on `UIScrollView`). If he has scrolled enough, animate the view to the opened position, otherwise animate it to the base position.

Answer (score 0):

```
try to add `CATransition` to your view
```

first add swipe gesture

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeLeft:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
[contentView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeRight:)];
[recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
[contentView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

handle swipe

```
-(void)handleSwipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype=kCATransitionFromRight;
    [contentView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

}

```
 -(void)handleSwipeRight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender{  

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype=kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [contentView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

}

dont forget to add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: Thank you this works great but if I can I'll try to do it with panGesture to have control on translation between two images. I never used panGesture so we'll see.